# Bitmap collision detection

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to make my app detect when two bitmaps intersect each other. This is the code I tried for collision:

```
 //width and height of the two bitmaps
int width1 = bplay1.getWidth();
int height1 = bplay1.getHeight();
int width2 = bbrick1.getWidth();
int height2 = bbrick1.getHeight(); 

if (height1 < height2)
   if ( width1 < width2)

{


        currentscore.setText("collision detected"); 

}
```

However, the app crashes on start when I use getHeight() and getWidth(). Am I doing something wrong with it?

Comment: You won't be able to check if to Bitmaps intersect by their widths and heights, the position will be necessary too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If it crashes, what output does it generate in the crash (in logcat)?
2. Assuming it crashes with null pointer exception (which to me seems most likely based on the very terse information you provided), you should make sure your bplay1 and/or bbrick1 objects are not null like so: `bplay1 = new MyClass();`

Summary: Whenever you post a S.O. question ask yourself this: If I found this post, what information would I be likely to need to solve it? In this specific case there is actually very little to go on.